# Information on visiting Iceland - tourism

Tags: planning, iceland

I am planning to travel to South Iceland for 3 days and 4 nights in February or March 2017. I want to do the following:

1. Jökulsárlón Lagoon Tour i.e. just see the glaciers floating on water from a distance (I am not planning to do any glacier walk/ excursions or things like that)
2. See the northern lights
3. Bathe in the Blue lagoon
4. Golden circle tour

Among the above four, the first two are my greatest priority. *I would like to know about the possible budget that will be required for each of the above four items*. Also how should I book the trips? *Is it possible to book the trips upon arrival on any hotel in Reykjavik?* Or is it compulsory to book them online prior to arrival in Iceland?  *Also please shed some light on your personal experience if you have already visited South Iceland. Other Comments or advice are also welcome.*

**EDIT for the last paragraph**

Among the above four, the first two are my greatest priority for which I would like to know the best time to travel to Iceland. Also I would like to know about the possible budget that will be required for each of the above four items.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: No need to book ahead, watch weather reports and predictions before booking anything. Going one day you might get lovely weather, the next day the lagoon boat tours (a great thing to do) are off because of strong winds and heavy rains. Blue Lagoon is the only thing I regret spending money on (and it can be very expensive.) Been there in September. Northern Lights 50% chance on the best days, almost no chance between March and October.

Comment: I did not post an answer as this question does show you have not done any research and it is too broad. It will likely be closed, as it is impossible to improve it into what is within the guidelines for the site.

Comment: I was in Iceland for the summer solstice. It was very expensive -- every part of it, from food to accommodation to tours. I was spending $USD 50 or more on a bunk bed in a hostel; a hot dog from a street vendor cost $6 or more. I would be very careful in budgeting for this trip.

Comment: You should make sure Jökulsárlón tours are on in February, I would expect everything to be frozen and snow-covered such that you don't see the glacier and icebergs, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I think you really need to break down this question into small pieces, that in itself are answerable in closed form! I.e. asking for best periods or rough price range might be ok, asking for opinions experiences is not. I have voted to close as too broad. Also make sure it does not look like asking for an itinerary from us, which is off-topic as well. Give a look to the [Help on Asking](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I feel this question is so broad that edits needed to keep it open are going to change it beyond recognition. The most recent edit is not going to do it for me at all.

Comment: @willeke- is the edit ok now?